# Cycling through the individual bits in a java BigInteger

Tags: java, cryptography, bit-manipulation, biginteger

I'm trying to implement some Montgomery math code for an encryption assignment; I have most of it working except for the step where I need to compare each individual bit in the BigInteger to One.

The math algorithm I've been using , from Step 4 is

```
for i = k - 1 down to 0 do
xBar = MonPro(xBar, xBar)
if e[i] = 1 then xBar = MonPro(MBar, xBar)
```

i is just an index, k is the number of bits in the BIgInteger, and b is the exponent. My attempt is:

```
for(int i = n.bitLength() - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    xBar = monPro(xBar, xBar, r, nPrime, n);
    if (n.testBit(i) == true)
         xBar = monPro(mBar, xBar, r, nPrime, n);
}
return monPro(xBar, BigINteger.ONE, r, nPrime, n);
```

monPro is a helper function that is definitely working. Likewise, the steps omitted before that code snippet definitely work. So the main question is, how do I bitwise iterate through a BigInteger? Unless I'm wrong about e[i], see below.

I've done an enormous amount of reading on this over the last while and resources are scant with regards to actual implementations. Some of the math papers published on the subject are purely mystifying.

I'm also unsure about is the e[i] above. In the book, it's e with a little i below it, the same way Log2 generally has the 2 written as a small number below it. Can anyone clarify?

I've tried casting the BigInteger to a base 2 string and making a char array out of and doing the compare to 1 on it. I also tried just BigInteger.toString(2) to make a base 2 string and cycle through that using charAt[i] == 1.

I'm certain that all the steps above the e[i] are correct because I've checked them with a lot of different values.

If I'm off the track on the E[i] aspect then could someone explain what it actually means? And if not could anyone point out any errors or slight direction?

This is a homework assignment so please don't list any code beyond snippets.

Any direction or advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why is `bitLength()` and `testBit()` not sufficient to bitwise iteration? Can `n` be negative?

Comment: I thought they should have been sufficient Micha, but they do not work in this context. Hence my confusion. And no, N can't be negative as far as I know.

Comment: sorry for the bad format, below a BigInteger test program:

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerBits {

 public static void main(final String[] args) {
  final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  BigInteger n;

  System.out.print("n = ");
  n = in.nextBigInteger();

  while (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0) {
   for (int i = n.bitLength(); i > 0; --i) {
    final char c = (n.testBit(i - 1) == true) ? '1' : '0';
    System.out.print(c);
   }
   System.out.println("");

   System.out.print("n = ");
   n = in.nextBigInteger();
  }

  in.close();
 }
}

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Maybe you should post that as an answer, correctly formatted of course?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Using `--i` in a for statement is a bit dangerous, as it does not do anything different from `i--`, it can put other developers on the wrong foot.

Comment: @owlstead I prefer `--i` over `i--` since `i--` might involve a temporary and `--i` is either equal or more efficient than `i--`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It's a preference of the programmer I suppose. Yours performs slightly better, my preference tilts a bit more towards readability :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = n.bitLength() - 1; i > 0 ; i--) { ... }
```

This will miss bit 0 (because when `i==0` the loop terminates.)
Try using `>=` instead of `>`:

```
for(int i = n.bitLength() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) { ... }
```

Alternatively, if you are using Java 7 *and* you know that `n` is positive, then you can convert it to a `BitSet` and iterate through its '1' bits:

```
static void showBitsOf(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must not be negative");
    }
    BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(n.toByteArray());
    for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just compare to >= 0 ?

Comment: @owlstead: you can (but that code would be longer than my example.)

Comment: By one character or so? And the devs have to know the for loop pretty well to know that the comparison expression is evaluated earlier then the increment part. Somehow I prefer to do increment/decrement in the increment part of a `for` loop. Maybe because it was made for that purpose.

Comment: @owlstead: I thought `for (i=N; i-->0;)` was a very common idiom in C and Java, but judging by the comment votes quite a few people are unfamiliar with it.  So I'll change it to the `>=` version.

Comment: it's not common within my company or the libraries I use, it's good to see that other people do you it, even if it does not have my preference. Thanks for the change.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I've managed to implement the Montgomery operations, but it turned out to be slower than my original right to left binary method by a magnitude of 3! Is this normal or do I have working but bungled?

Comment: I posted the code on code review if anyone is interested in having a look at it - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18199/optimization-of-exponentiation